# How to set up Variants for Entry Points of additional languages in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

The final domains of the project will be:

1. www.domain.com (english, main language, L=0)
2. www.domain.de (german, L=1)

The development/preview domains are

1. dev.domain.com
2. dev.domain.de

It is possible to create a Variant for the main "Entry Point" in tab "General" of the Site Configuration:
Base: https://dev.domain.com/
Condition: applicationContext == "Development"

But how can I set up a variant for the second language (german)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as long as you need no other language specific configuration, you could set env vars in your apache configuration and read them in your site configuration. This is officially supported (see [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UsingEnvVars.html))

Site config:

```
base: 'https://%env(BASE_DOMAIN)%/'
languages:
  -
    base: 'https://%env(BASE_DOMAIN_DE)%/'
```

Apache config (example):

```
SetEnvIf Host ".*" TYPO3_CONTEXT=Production
SetEnvIf Host ".*" BASE_DOMAIN=www.domain.com
SetEnvIf Host ".*" BASE_DOMAIN_DE=www.domain.de
SetEnvIf Host "dev.domain.com" TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development
SetEnvIf Host "dev.domain.com" BASE_DOMAIN=dev.domain.com
SetEnvIf Host "dev.domain.de" TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development
SetEnvIf Host "dev.domain.de" BASE_DOMAIN_DE=dev.domain.de
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks!
The Apache config con be shortened by two lines (production is default, .domain.com not needed, because it never contains "dev"):
`SetEnvIf Host ".*" BASE_DOMAIN=www.domain.com`  
`SetEnvIf Host ".*" BASE_DOMAIN_DE=www.domain.de`  
`SetEnvIf Host "dev" TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development`  
`SetEnvIf Host "dev" BASE_DOMAIN=dev.domain.com`  
`SetEnvIf Host "dev" BASE_DOMAIN_DE=dev.domain.de`

Comment: In 10.4.2 this gets cached: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91443

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet possible. The related issue can be checked out at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86400.

I would solve that in the meantime by using different `config.yml` files.

Answer (score 1):

Since TYPO3 v9.5.5 baseVariants can be added directly in yaml for "base" values of site languages, the same way as the default "base" property in the site.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's great! I just tried it and it worked like a charm. There is one thing to keep in mind though: it will be overwritten if you edit something via the sitemanager afterwards (e.g. if you edit the error handling) without warning. For this reason, I would stay with Mikel's solution for the time being.

Comment: Regarding this, [your issue 87831](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87831)  is related to [Issue 86400](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86400). I'm unsure if I should add a relation to a "Resolved" issue in this case. Just wanted to let you know :-)