# Multi-domain setup for one root in TYPO3 9.5?

Tags: installation, typo3, multiple-domains, typo3-9.x

I have problem configuring my old site which I upgraded to 9.5. I had multidomain setup using landing pages with one root (home) using typoscript. 
There is a new module Sites, but there i can put only one domain, i can put other in list module but then if I access site with other urls, home is configured ok using my typoscript options and works good, but all links are with domain from site configuration.

is is possible to configure this somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you just enter / as "Entry Point" instead of a domain? If It's also about languages you may have a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54852662/how-to-set-up-variants-for-entry-points-of-additional-languages-in-typo3). Consider that the same content under different domains will be [duplicate content](https://www.sistrix.com/ask-sistrix/onpage-optimisation/duplicate-content/).

Comment: That worked like a charm Ben, thank you very much :)

Comment: I see one problem. If you use /  => sitemaps will be generated with relative url´s => which google seach console does not accept. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Do you really need multiple domains or would it be an option to redirect the other domains to one canonical domain?

Answer (score 4):

Solution is to put just "/" in entry point, credits to Ben for this, thanks again.